# How do I set Gatsby Link to be an <li> tag instead of an <a> tag?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am building a Gatsby site and I have the following HTML structure for the website's menu:

```
<li className="menu-item current-menu-item">
  <Link to="/">Home</Link>
</li>
<li className="menu-item">
  <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
</li>
```

As you can see, the active class is applied to the `<li>` tag and not the `<a>` tag that is generated by `<Link>`. In Vue, we can do something like this:

```
<router-link to="/contact" tag="li">
  <a href="javascript:void">Contact</a>
</router-link>
```

The `tag` prop tells the `router-link` element that it should render the element as a list item. This way, the active class is applied to the list item and not to the child `<a>` tag. How do I achieve the same result with Gatsby Link? I can't seem to find an answer to this anywhere. Thank you.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by rendering a different element? Surely a link should be an `<a>`?

Comment: I'm converting an HTML theme that I purchased on ThemeForest to Gatsby. I notice that a lot of themes tend to apply the active class on the `<li>` element and not to the child `<a>` element. I could modify the CSS to set the active class on the `<a>` element but that would require changing the theme's source files which isn't ideal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want to use a `li` *instead* of an `a` tag. You just want the `li` to show as active when the corresponding `a` tag is active. Links should be `a` tags as an HTML standard.

Gatsby uses `reach-router` for routing, so when working with paths and routing, you can use the `globalHistory` object to get the current path:

```
import { globalHistory } from '@reach/router'
```

Then inside your component, get the `pathname` of the current path:

```
const pathname = globalHistory.location.pathname
```

Now all you do is conditionally set the style of each `li`, based on the value of `pathname`:

```
<li className={`menu-item ${pathname === "/" ? "current-menu-item" : ""} `}>
  <Link to="/">Home</Link>
</li>
<li className={`menu-item ${pathname === "/contact" ? "current-menu-item" : ""} `}>
  <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
</li>
```

It might be easier to have an array of your links:

```
const navLinks = [
  { label: 'Home', to: '/' },
  { label: 'Contact', to: '/contact' },
  { label: 'About', to: '/about' },
]
```

And then map over them inside the return statement instead of writing them out individually:

```
return (
  <ul>
    {navLinks.map(link => (
      <li className={`menu-item ${pathname === link.to ? 'current-menu-item' : ''} `}>
        <Link to={link.to}>{link.label}</Link>
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
)
```